# Mapping subclass values in Entity Framework TPH

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm setting up a TPH inheritance in C# MVC for the first time, and I'm a bit confused on how to map subclass values to the table. For example, my parent entity's fluent map is declared using:

```
public class ProjectTaskMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProjectTask>
```

I have individual maps set up using:

```
Map<ProjectTL>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("TL"));
```

As a further example: One of the subclasses needs to have a many-to-many mapping. I don't know how to configure that with TPH since I can't access the child class's properties to declare the mapping.

I can't access the subclass properties in this parent map, however (since it's calling the config of `ProjectTask`). I can't specify how to map a field to the table, I can't do anything with them.

What am I missing to be able to do this? This is an old system that was just upgraded to EF 6.1, so I don't have EF Designer or anything like that, only these fluent mappings.

Parent class:

```
public class ProjectTask : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual int ProjectId { get; set; }
    // various other properties

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectTaskFile> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Two child classes have none of their own properties (they're empty shells), but the third does. `ECOs` is part of a many-to-many relationship.

```
public class ProjectET : ProjectTask
{
    public virtual int SalesOrderId { get; set; }

    public virtual SalesOrder SalesOrder { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EngChangeOrders> ECOs { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: please, provide the structure your classes (ProjectTask, ProjectTL)

Comment: @FabioLuz: I've added them to the post.

Comment: Hi! I am struggling with the same problem, did you manage to find an answer here?

Answer (score 0):

When creating your model with Code First, TPH is the default strategy for the types that participate in the inheritance hierarchy. Take a look at the following structure:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectTask
{
    public int ProjectTaskId { get; set; }

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectET : ProjectTask
{
    public ICollection<Order> ECOs { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context() : base("Model2")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProjectET> ProjectETs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
            .HasKey(i => i.ProjectId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectTask>()
            .HasKey(i => i.ProjectTaskId);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }


}
```

Migrations Generated

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.ProjectTasks",
            c => new
                {
                    ProjectTaskId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    SomeString = c.String(),
                    Discriminator = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Project_ProjectId = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ProjectTaskId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Projects", t => t.Project_ProjectId)
            .Index(t => t.Project_ProjectId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Orders",
            c => new
                {
                    OrderId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    SomeString = c.String(),
                    ProjectET_ProjectTaskId = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.OrderId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.ProjectTasks", t => t.ProjectET_ProjectTaskId)
            .Index(t => t.ProjectET_ProjectTaskId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Projects",
            c => new
                {
                    ProjectId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ProjectId);
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: These are set up using individual mappings in the style that I posted, I can't get around that. I have to use fluent mapping inside a map for a specific class.

Comment: Your final database structure should be the same as shown in the Migrations above?

Answer (score 0):

Your fluent config can obviously only address a single entity type at a time, but there's nothing stopping you from adding fluent config for your subclass *as well*. Not sure what the complication is here.

```
public class ProjectETMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProjectET>
{
    public ProjectETMap()
    {
        HasMany(m => m.ECOs).WithMany();
    }
}
```